# checkbox button in tableview in Swift

Tags: swift, checkbox, tableview, uitableview

I'm trying to create a checkbox functionality in a tableview . 
It's a to-do list where if the checkbox is pressed the cell hides and appears as completed in a different section.

Coming from C# this was very straightforward to do but in swift there isn't even a checkbox button to start with :(...

I made it to work by adding a button with two images(checked, unchecked) to a custom prototype cell in IB.
Since you can't have the tableView and the in-cell-button declared in the same viewcontroller/class I had to subclass the tableViewCell.

Now, how do I access the checkbox from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` ? When I select the cell the event fires but when I press the checkbox button in the same cell nothing fires and I can't hide the cell.

```
var indexTag = checkBoxImage.tag
//this is what I have in TableViewCell class

@IBAction func checkBoxInCell(sender: UIButton) {

   checkBoxImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"checked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

   if isChecked != false {
        isChecked = false
        cellitemcontent.removeAtIndex(indexTag)
        //can't access the cell from here to update the tableview
   } 
   else {
        isChecked = true
        checkBoxImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"unchecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}

//this is what I have in my FirstViewController that contains the tableview

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{        
     cellitemcontent.removeAtIndex(indexTag)
     tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
     //when I press the checkBoxImage button in the cell it doesn't fire this event...       
}
```

Comment: I struggled with the same thing. http://blog.johnregner.com/post/106662696360/chapter-15-uitableviewcell-actions. I found an answer I liked from Mike Abdullah http://mikeabdullah.net/thl-diary-19.1.html

Comment: that looks like a good idea but it looks like I'm not knowledgeble enough to translate that into swift. I'll let you know if I succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what you are trying to accomplish, but I would tackle it a different way.  Perhaps in your model, you could have an array of tasks that are pending, and another array of tasks that are completed.

The number of sections can be 2.  The number of rows in sections 0 and 1 can be the number of elements in the first and second arrays respectively.

When `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, you can remove the item at that index in the first array and add the task to the second array.  Then you must call `tableView.reloadData()`.

I know you want to just pick up the row and change the placement of it, but in iOS the cells get reused.  It's best to update the data source and then reload the table.

For the checkmarks, you can ensure that the items in Section 0 do not have the checkmark accessory, while the items in Section 1 do.  You would set the accessory in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after the cell has been dequeued.

Comment: Hm, that's an interesting approach but I still won't be able to fire the event when I press the checkBox button within that  cell because only the actual selection of the cell will fire it. Is there other cell event that I'm missing? Why is the button within the cell not considered a part of the cell when selected?

Comment: I tend to look at the table view cell as a generic object that has no idea what data it holds. Subclass uitableviewcell and add a unbutton to it. If you make the button accessible, then in cellforrowatindex, you can set the buttons tag: cell.button.tag = indexPath.row. Then create a method: -(void) buttonTouched: (UIButton *) sender and set the button's target in cellforrowatindex.  Therefore, when any button is tapped, it will call buttonTouched, and you can get the row through sender.tag.

Comment: In other words, the cell just knows which row it's in, and the button now knows too because of the tag.

Comment: Thanks Josh, - Subclass uitableviewcell and add a unbutton to it |Done| - set the buttons tag: cell.button.tag = indexPath.row |Done| - create a method: -(void) buttonTouched: (UIButton *) sender not sure how to do that - set the button's target in cellforrowatindex, |Done|.
How do I create the method?

Comment: Sorry... Swift not objective -c. . Create the function func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton){}

Comment: the func checkBoxInCell is my button touched function. the sender.tag I can access it with just cell.button.tag = indexPath.row in didSelectRowAtIndex without even creating the target but I'm still unable to access the tableView inside the buttonTouched because it's in a different class....grrr this is getting so frustrating, I spent 2 nights on this already...:( do you happen to know how to access the tableview outside it's class?

Comment: When the button is touched, it should call func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton){[self.tableView.reloadData()}... so you need to set the target.  I'll write the code for you.  One sec.

Answer (score 2):

I use sample code below to implement check box button in cell (Xcode 7/ Swift 2.0):
-In viewDidLoad {}:(save check box state in each cell to .plist file)

```
 let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString


    let fnstring = (documentsPath as String)+"/yr-filename.plist"
    let fM = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    //if (let  a != (fM.fileExistsAtPath(fnstring))) {
    if !(fM.fileExistsAtPath(fnstring)) {
        let onlyarr = NSMutableArray()
        for var i = 0 ; i < 5; ++i{ // number of sections

            var arr = NSArray()
            switch i { // number cell in each section
                case 0: arr = [Int](count: 12, repeatedValue: 0) // 0 means unchecked box.
                case 1: arr =  [Int](count: 13, repeatedValue: 0)
                case 2: arr =  [Int](count: 14, repeatedValue: 0)
                case 3: arr =  [Int](count: 15, repeatedValue: 0)
                case 4: arr =  [Int](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0) 
                default: arr = [Int]()   
            }
            onlyarr.addObject(arr)
            }
            onlyarr.writeToFile(fnstring, atomically: false)  
    }
```

- In override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let fnstring = (documentsPath as String)+"/yr-filename.plist"
    let fM = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fM.fileExistsAtPath(fnstring) {
    let chcklstDick = NSMutableArray(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fnstring))
    let chcklstsortedCat: NSArray? = chcklstDick
    let ttt: NSMutableArray = chcklstsortedCat?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as! NSMutableArray
        if ttt.count > 0 {  
            var img = UIImage()
             let j : Int = ttt.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! Int
            NSLog("j: %i", j)
            if j > 0 {
                img = UIImage(named: "checked")!
            }else {
                img = UIImage(named: "unchecked")!
            }
            let bttn : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            bttn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)
            bttn.setBackgroundImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            bttn.addTarget(self, action:"chckBttnTapped:eventy:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            cell.accessoryView = bttn
        }

    }else {NSLog("nonononononononno")}
```

- In func chckBttnTapped(sender: AnyObject, eventy event: AnyObject) { }

```
 let touches: NSSet = event.allTouches()!
    let touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject()! as! UITouch
    let crrntTouchPos : CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.tableView)
    let idxpth: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(crrntTouchPos)!
   if idxpth.row != NSNotFound {
       self.tableView(self.tableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: idxpth)
    }
```

-In override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { }

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let fnstring = (documentsPath as String)+"/yr-filename.plist"
    let fM = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fM.fileExistsAtPath(fnstring) {
        let chcklstDick = NSMutableArray(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fnstring))
        let chcklstsortedCat: NSMutableArray? = chcklstDick 
        let ttt: NSMutableArray = chcklstsortedCat?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as! NSMutableArray
        if ttt.count > 0 {
            let j : Int = ttt.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! Int
            var newimg = UIImage()
            if j == 0 {
                newimg = UIImage(named: "checked")!
            }else {
                newimg = UIImage(named: "unchecked")!
            }

             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellID", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let bttn : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            bttn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newimg.size.width, newimg.size.height)
            bttn.setBackgroundImage(newimg, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            bttn.addTarget(self, action:"chckBttnTapped:eventy:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            cell.accessoryView = bttn
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.reloadInputViews()
            ttt.replaceObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row, withObject: 1 - j)
            chcklstsortedCat?.replaceObjectAtIndex(indexPath.section, withObject: ttt)
            chcklstsortedCat?.writeToFile(fnstring, atomically: false)
        }
    }
```

Hope its useful.